# Every new entry INSERT only Unique data from One Table to Another in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying for hours and no luck. I made a form where user post their data I have done everything just this last thing which i cant figure this out. I am not a pro so I am sorry if i have done something out of the way to my code or If someone already asked this question before but none of their solutions work for me. 
I want to Insert the data from one table to another but only unique data not the existing one on every new entry.

I have done something like this:

```
$wesr = ("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE product='$name'");
 $check_name = mysqli_query($db_conn, $wesr);
  $check_num_rows_npos = mysqli_num_rows($check_namepos);

  $wesre = ("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE manu='$manu'");
  $check_nameposs = mysqli_query($db_conn, $wesre);
  $check_num_rows_nposs = mysqli_num_rows($check_nameposs);

if ($check_num_rows_npos > 0) {
    $sql554343 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table2";
} elseif ($check_num_rows_nposs > 0) {
    $sql5547722 = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table2";
} else {
    $sqlfin565= "INSERT INTO table2 (name, manu) SELECT (name, manu) FROM table1";

$resultf445i = mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlfin565);
}
```

Any help appreciated..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unique data? If the name - manu pair already exists in table2, then you do not want to insert the same name - manu pair into table 2?

Comment: Simply use this `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE product='$name' AND manu='$manu'` and the results will be unique.

Comment: Unique means there are many products from different manufacturers. Every user post the different product and manufacturer namw thats the unique data and the entry which is post by the user.. I am select this data from table 1 and insert it into table 2. Both table have the same columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accept only Unique data and IGNORE same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421875/accept-only-unique-data-and-ignore-same-data)